# Mediaqueries incorrect behavior

Tags: css

I'm working with mediaqueryes but I don't understand why they don't work correctly I have 3 navbars and I would like to show and hide them according to the measures

navbar names:

```
#navbar_uno
#navbar_due
#navbar_tre
```

media queries

```
 /* Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)*/
    @media (max-width: 575px) {
        #navbar_uno{display: none;}
        #navbar_due{display: none;}
    }

    /* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)*/
    @media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        #navbar_uno{display: none;}
        #navbar_due{display: none;}
    }

    /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)*/
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        #navbar_uno{display: none;}
        #navbar_due{display: none;}
    }

    /* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)*/
    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        #navbar_uno{display: none;}
        #navbar_due{display: none;}
    }

    /* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)*/
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        #navbar_uno{display: none;}
        #navbar_due{display: none;}
    }
```

in theory navbar_3, you should always see me and it is not like that, why?

```
<nav id="navbar_uno" class='navigation'>
...
</nav>

<nav id="navbar_tre" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color">
...
</nav>

<nav id="navbar_due"  class="navigation navigation--relative navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  lighten-3 d-block">
...
 </nav>
```

Comment: Did you misspell `#navbar_tre` vs `#navbar_3`? Show the HTML.

Comment: @MarkusZeller update question

Comment: Does it work if you remove all the classes from the navs in your HTML?

Comment: What's the CSS of `#navbar_uno` `#navbar_due` and `#navbar_tre` ? (not the mediaqueries)

Comment: Also, what is the point of these media queries ? For any size screen, you have `#navbar_uno` and `#navbar_due` which are on `display:none` so they never appear

Answer (score -1):

There might be some other styles being applied to your navbar3